# How to make RootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

### i want to make navigation controller by coding but there is a problem : below is my code

this is Appdelegates.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *firstVC = [[ViewController alloc] init ];//WithNibName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *naviCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
    naviCtrl.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.window.rootViewController = naviCtrl;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

and This is my rootviewController.m :-

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "DetailsViewController.h"




    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    #pragma mark
    #pragma mark ViewDidLoad method
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    //    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray ];
    //    indicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    //    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
    //    indicator.alpha = 1.0;
    //    [indicator startAnimating];
    //    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    //    [self performSelector:@selector(stopActivity:) withObject:nil afterDelay:8];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        [self CreateView];
    }
    -(void)stopActivity:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)ActivityIndictor{
        [ActivityIndictor removeFromSuperview];

    }

    #pragma mark
    #pragma mark CreateView Method
    -(void)CreateView{
        int space = 3;
        UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
        [scrollview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 1000)];
        [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        //[scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [scrollview setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [scrollview setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [[self view] addSubview:scrollview];
        //scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

}
```

But there is a problem ,in my view controller viewdidload is not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet of a full implementation for

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

Implementation with root and navigation controller without storyboard just with nib-files:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

LoginViewController *newRootViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newRootViewController];
    newRootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//Preload keyboard to delete delay on first appereance in UITextFields
UITextField *delayFreeField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:delayFreeField];
[delayFreeField becomeFirstResponder];
[delayFreeField resignFirstResponder];
[delayFreeField removeFromSuperview];

return YES;
```

Comment: can i simply "init" my view controller?

Comment: Yes of course! That snippet is plus code for a delay free UITextField... It's from an actual working application.

Comment: but when i do that  i face some problem just like in rootViewcontroller ViewDidLoad is not working

Comment: Then your RootViewController is not working properly. Just use a generic one for testing purposes.

Comment: No, the problem is that if you simply 'init' it you are not loading a view. You need to initialize it using a xib file to make the viewDidLoad work

Comment: ...and init your Controller with a nib file, just create one via Xcode and all files are given to you in a working state with a white colored view that is ready for further customization.

Comment: You have to use: [YourViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewControllerName" bundle:nil] thats it. Pretty easy. As I said, just create one with Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you RootController is initialized with this line of code:

```
ViewController *firstVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

The ViewDidLoad method doesn't work because your are not loading a view from a Nib, but you are simply creating an instance of a class.

Try to initialize the controller with:

```
ViewController *firstVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:nil];
```

where `LaunchScreen` is the name of the Xib of your main RootController (the one you called `ViewController` ). If the xib is well prepared, the ViewDidLoad method will work.

Answer (score -5):

set up your properties however youre used to 
also in xcode in your general project settings you might need to delete the "main interface".  also delete the default storyboard if you dont want it and clean your project.  and delete the app from your simulator or device then rebuild it.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    [navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the "[navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];"? It pushes a new controller on the screen over the application main view, you are not putting it on the main view directly. (with this code your controller will basically popup from the bottom to the top of the screen.)

Comment: i want to make root view controller  in app delegates , not push view controller ,,,,,and why i need to do that ....

Comment: look at his original question and original code.  he is instantiating a nav controller and a view controller.  hence me thinking that's what he is trying to do.  also in reference to your question regarding pushing a view controller... initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController ....... (from docs) This is a convenience method for initializing the receiver and pushing a root view controller onto the navigation stack. Every navigation stack must have at least one view controller to act as the root.